# Analytical expression of sum of Sines

Tags: trigonometry

Express E and F in terms of A,B,C,D

$Asin(B+x) + Csin(D+x) = Esin(F+x)$

Can you also find a general formula for more number of terms on the left-hand side?

$A_{1}sin(B_{1}+x)+A_{2}sin(B_{2}+x)+...+A_{n}sin(B_{n}+x)=Esin(F+x)  $

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I actually didn't think of expanding the left-hand side until Bernard Pan said it below

Answer (score 0):

Here are the hints to the first one.

For the LHS, we have $$A\sin(B+x)=A(\sin B\cos x+\cos B\sin x), $$similarly, $$C\sin(D+x)=C(\sin D\cos x+\cos D\sin x). $$Thus, $$A\sin(B+x)+C\sin(D+x)=\sin x(A\cos B+C\cos D)+\cos x(A\sin B+C\sin D). $$

Recall that $$m\sin x+n\cos x=\sqrt{m^2+n^2}\sin(x+\varphi),\quad\varphi=\arctan\frac{n}{m}.$$

Then I think it is easy to get the expressions for both $E$ and $F$. As for the generalized form, you can just take a similar approach and it is actually no more difficult than the first one.

Comment: nice one, expanding left-hand side terms and then factorising, I'll write up the general solution in a few minutes, thanks

Comment: There's a small problem here though, I'm on Desmos trying the formula for just two terms and the arctan is sometimes off by a shift of Pi

Comment: Figured that carrying over the sign of sine to the right-hand side fixes the problem actually, so I added an extra term B/abs(B)

Answer (score 0):

$A_{1}sin(B_{1}+x)+A_{2}sin(B_{2}+x)+...+A_{n}sin(B_{n}+x)=Esin(F+x)$

$A_{1}sin(B_{1})cos(x)+A_{1}cos(B_{1})sin(x)+...$ so factorising $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$  will give the coefficients:

$A_{s}=A_{1}sin(B_{1})+A_{2}sin(B_{2})+...+A_{n}sin(B_{n})$

$B_{s}=A_{1}cos(B_{1})+A_{2}cos(B_{2})+...+A_{n}cos(B_{n})$

where the LHS = $A_{s}cos(x)+B_{s}sin(x)$

since $Acos(x)+Bsin(x) = \frac{B}{|B|}\sqrt{{A}^2+{B}^2}*sin(arctan(\frac{A}{B})+x)$ then:

$Esin(F+x)=\frac{B_{s}}{|B_{s}|}\sqrt{{A_{s}}^2+{B_{s}}^2}*sin(arctan(\frac{A_{s}}{B_{s}})+x)$

so $E=\frac{B_{s}}{|B_{s}|}\sqrt{{A_{s}}^2+{B_{s}}^2}$ and $F=arctan(\frac{A_{s}}{B_{s}})$